# IE top left corner border diffrent

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

IE border drawing and chrome border drawing is different. Here is my problem css and screenshot (with zoom)

```
.test {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid green;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Chrome:
[image]

IE:
[image]

Chrome and other browsers top left corner is green, but in IE red. This is making problem in my desing, how can I fix this problem?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yLdF4/

**EDIT:** Here is my real problem screenshot;
[image][image]

Little annoying 1 pixel.

Comment: If you tell what kind of effect you want to achieve, then there will be a solution. e.g. you could use two nested div, one with `left` and `right` border and the other with `top` and `bottom`

Comment: This is probably the smallest problem I ever have seen asked at SO, just one pixel ; ).

Comment: yes just one pixel but annoying :) I added new screenshot, look at ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think either of the browsers is wrong in this case; they've just implemented the same standard slightly differently. The corner of the border in this sort of case is specified to be a diagonal line separating the two colours. Of course when it's only a single pixel wide, a diagonal line is fairly meaningless; the spec doesn't say to prefer the vertical or horizontal line, so there's room for slightly the different interpretations you see here.

If you really need to *guarantee* the colours in this case, I would suggest using `:before` and `:after` to create the borders on the sides separately from the main box.